# How to pass data from Interceptor to URL and JSP?

Tags: struts2, interceptor

I have an authen interceptor that check if user is logged in.
If not than it will redirect to the login page, with a query string param "url" indicating the referrer URL. I tried using "actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getParameters()" for passing values to the redirect URL, but have no luck.

Can anyone suggest what I done wrong? Thanks a lot.

**Interceptor code:**

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
    Map session = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();
    Map params = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getParameters();

    String user = (String) session.get(Constants.KEY_USER);

    boolean isAuthenticated = (null!=user);

    if (!isAuthenticated) {
        params.put("backUrl", "http://www.some_url.com/");
        return Action.LOGIN;            
    }
    else {
        return actionInvocation.invoke();
    }
}
```

**struts.xml parts**

```
<global-results>
   <result name="login" type="redirect">/login?url=${backUrl}</result>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the **order of the interceptors** in your `struts.xml` file; params interceptor should be placed before login interceptor:

```
 <interceptor-stack name="defaultLoginStack">
      ...
      <interceptor-ref name="params" />
      <interceptor-ref name="login" />
      ...
 </interceptor-stack>
```

Here's an [example](http://www.vitarara.org/cms/book/export/html/121)

Another way to get the query string, is from the attribute `javax.servlet.forward.query_string`:

```
 String queryString = (String) actionInvocation.getRequest().
      getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.query_string");
```